# django extend ModelAdmin fieldsets and keep defaults

Tags: django-admin

is there a nice way to **add** custom items to a subclassed ModelAdmin fieldset, ie have it keep all the defaults and just some extras.

(i know i could add all the defaults back myself, but was hoping for a nicer way)

Answer (score 14):

You can override **get_fieldsets** method of ModelAdmin.

The default implementation looks like this:

```
def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
    "Hook for specifying fieldsets for the add form."
    if self.declared_fieldsets:
        return self.declared_fieldsets
    form = self.get_form(request, obj)
    fields = form.base_fields.keys() + list(self.get_readonly_fields(request, obj))
    return [(None, {'fields': fields})]
```

So you can override it for example like this:

```
class MyCustomAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        fs = super(MyCustomAdmin, self).get_fieldsets(request, obj)
        # fs now contains [(None, {'fields': fields})], do with it whatever you want
        all_fields = fs[0][1]['fields']
        return fs
```

Answer (score 2):

Untested, but may work:

```
class MyAdmin(BaseAdmin):
    fieldsets = BaseAdmin.fieldsets + (...)
```

This would (if it works) add the other fieldsets after the inherited ones.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of extending a custom ModelAdmin class and adding an extra fieldset.

Note the first time I tried this, I left out the "if not ..." check. Every time I refreshed the page, the extra sections were repeated on the page.

```
class GISDataFileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # abbreviated version of detailed fieldsets (one fieldset named 'Datafile Info')
    fieldsets = [('DataFile Info', {\
              'fields': ('datafile_id', 'datafile_label', 'datafile_version')\
               }),]

class ShapefileSetAdmin(GISDataFileAdmin):    

    # extend fieldsets in GISDataFileAdmin
    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):

        # get fieldset(s) from GISDataFileAdmin
        #
        fs = super(ShapefileSetAdmin, self).get_fieldsets(request, obj)  

        # pull out the fieldset name(s) e.g. [ 'DataFile Info']
        #
        section_names = [ x[0] for x in fs if x is not None and len(x) > 0 and not x[0] == '']   

        # check if new fieldset info has been added
        # if not, add the new fieldset
        #
        if not 'Shapefile Info' in sections_names:   
            # Add new info as the top fieldset
            fs = [ ('Shapefile Info', {
               'fields': ('name', ('zipfile_checked',  'has_shapefile'))
                    })] + fs
        return fs
```

Answer (score 0):

#models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser, TimeStamped):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, blank=False, 
     null=False)
   
    is_premium = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

#admin.py

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
model = CustomUser
add_form = CustomUserCreationForm   
fieldsets = (
    (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
    (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'is_premium')}),
    (_('Permissions'), {
        'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'groups', 'user_permissions'),
    }),
    (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
)
admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

you just need to grab the default fieldsets from UserAdmin, and update it in your CustomUserAdmin.